# JPA Entity name value compare with values in table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i was trying to compare the entity name with the values in my table. i dont understand how to get the entity name in a class.

@Entity(name ="somename")

here i want to access the name value someone in a class.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fetch the `name` value of the Annotation (if set).

```
Entity entity = YourEntity.class.getAnnotation(Entity.class);
if (entity != null) {
    String optionalName = entity.name();
}
```

Be aware that it is an optional value, so it does not allways reflect the actual Database table name (if unset).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to get the table name from the model in Hibernate.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
...

Entity entity = YourEntity.class.getAnnotation(Entity.class);
String entityName = entity.name();
```